# CDK (as3) false positives when using it with array elements

Tags: collision-detection, flash, actionscript-3

I'm having problems when using the CDK (Collision Detection Kit) with elements in an array. It keeps getting me false positives of collision.

I'm making a game in which the player controls a “ship”, that has to avoid both enemies and the terrain in which it moves through, like a “tunnel” with obstacles. To make the “tunnel” random every time, I emit “pieces” of different walls into stage so it seems like an infinite tunnel with obstacles inside. In order to do this, I created an array, called wallArray, which stores the display objects from the class Walls, which is the class where in each frame, there's a different shape of wall.

Everything works like a charm, except the collision, which uses CDK. I'm using the regular CollisionList method:

```
//On the document class, on the enter frame (eventListener) function:
wallArray[(index - 1)].x -= wall_mov_speed;
wallArray[index].x -= wall_mov_speed;
if(wallArray[index].x < 0){
    spawn_wall_piece();
}
if(index == 5){
//We call this function for cleaning the array and readding walls to it
    adequate_array_of_walls(false);
}
if(wall_mov_speed < 15){
    wall_mov_speed += 0.009;
}

wall_collisions = myWallCollisionList.checkCollisions();

if(wall_collisions.length > 0){
    trace("hit!");
    if(myShip.visible == true){
        //We only kill the ship if it's visible, if not, it means it is already dead
        Ship.receiveDamage(Ship.max_health);
     }
    wall_collisions = 0 as Array;
}
```

And here we have the functions for rearranging the wallArray, also in the document class (and where I add the elements to the CollisionList):

```
function adequate_array_of_walls(init:Boolean):void{
    //This only executes if we are initialitizing the array
    if(init == true){
        for(index = 0; index < 10; index++){
            var aWall:Walls = new Walls();
            randomize = Math.floor(Math.random()*4) + 1;
            aWall.gotoAndStop(randomize);
            wallArray.push(aWall);
            myWallCollisionList.addItem(wallArray[index]);
        }
        wallArray[0].gotoAndStop(1);
        stage.addChild(wallArray[0]);
        wallArray[1].x = 800;
        wallArray[1].y = 0;
        stage.addChild(wallArray[1]);
    //if not, then we are just cleaning it so it doesn't grow bigger and bigger
    }else{
        for(var a:Number = 0; a < index - 1; a++){
            myWallCollisionList.removeItem(wallArray[a]);
            wallArray.splice(0,1);
        }
        for(a = index - 1; a < (10-2); a++){
            var aWall2:Walls = new Walls();
            randomize = Math.floor(Math.random()*4) + 1;
            aWall2.gotoAndStop(randomize);
            wallArray.push(aWall2);
            myWallCollisionList.addItem(wallArray[a]);
        }
    }
    //Then, either way, we tell index to be 1 since the reference in the function is [index - 1] and [index], so it starts with [0] and [1]
    index = 1;
}
function spawn_wall_piece(){
    index++;
    wallArray[index].x = (wallArray[index - 1].x + wallArray[index - 1].width);
    wallArray[index].y = 0;
    stage.addChild(wallArray[index]);
    stage.removeChild(wallArray[index - 2]);
}
```

Well, as I said, everything works except the collision, it keeps me detecting collisions even though there's none. I was troubled that it was the walls' too intrincate shape, but tried this method before even with mazes and worked perfectly. I don't know what could cause this, am I missing something?

I would appreciate very much any help or comment.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: I post the full code related to the wall collision to cover every possibility just in case:

```
package  { 
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Stage;
import com.coreyoneil.collision.CollisionList;
//...

public class Game extends MovieClip {
    //...
    //Wall generation variables
    static var wall_mov_speed:Number;
    var randomize:Number;
    var wallArray:Array = new Array();
    var index:int = 0;
    //
    //Wall collision variables
    var myWallCollisionList:CollisionList = new CollisionList(myShip);
    var wall_collisions:Array = new Array();
    //
    //...
    public function Game() {
        //...
        //Movement speed of the walls
        wall_mov_speed = 8;
        //Calling to the generating/adequating wallArray function
        adequate_array_of_walls(true);
        //
        //Collision managements
        wall_collisions = 0 as Array;
        //
        //...
    }
```

Comment: I keep seeing `myWallCollisionList.addItem`. How many items are there? You are not supposed to clear it up?

Comment: Oh, yeah that wasn't cleaned. Thanks for pointing it out! Will try and inform of the results.

Comment: No, still no result. Added this line: myWallCollisionList.removeItem(wallArray[a]); when rearranging the array, but it doesn't work. The ship keeps dying again and again without touching anything. Any other ideas? Thanks for your help again!

Comment: You might wish to update the code in case someone wants to chime in. What is `a` and where and when do you remove the walls?

Comment: You should start debugging by printing (tracing) the # of elements in your collision list.

Comment: Hi again! Well, `a` is just another index for the "for" loop so that to use it without changing the index itself in the wallArray. I remove the walls in the line where it says  `wallArray.splice(0,1);`. And yes, I've done the thing of tracing the length of the array, and it keeps fixed in 10 elements. About the code, I thougth too much would "scare" readers (it'd seem long and boring), so I left out part of it. Nonetheless, I have no problem in uploading it, I'll edit the code and include var declarations and so. I will keep looking for the problem, but for now I have no clue. Thank you again!

Comment: Did you test the most simple base case? Do you have a short piece of code that tests the basic case?

Comment: Yes, I have it. I did a test to check everything was fine, and with the same method and same shapes, tested the CDK but without the array mess, and it worked as expected, so it can't be for the shape now. Only other option is the array thing. Will try now and inform later. But the way, I tried the array thing with Grant Skinner's collision method and didn't work either, so it is pretty sure there's some coding issue here.

Comment: Maybe you are not rendering the same thing you're checking for collision?

Comment: I think I do not quite understand. Are you suggesting that maybe I'm checking for an element that is not the one I want? If so, I'll check again, but I think `wallArray[index]` and `wallArray[index - 1]` are valid display objects, and the target is defined in the variable declaration. As far as I know, collisionList checks a relationship of one-to-many. Could you please explain again? I'm sorry I don't catch what you are saying. Thanks again.

Comment: Hey, finally found the solution!! I will post it right now. Thank you for your help though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so finally I found a solution for it!

The reason for the method to fail was that I added the items for collision when I initialized or rearranged the wallArray. I must have had done something wrong and it didn't work. However, if I added the items in the `spawn_wall_piece()` function, there's no problem:

```
function spawn_wall_piece(){
    index++;
    wallArray[index].x = (wallArray[index - 1].x + wallArray[index - 1].width);
    wallArray[index].y = 0;
    stage.addChild(wallArray[index]);
    myWallCollisionList.addItem(wallArray[index]);
    myWallCollisionList.removeItem(wallArray[index - 2]);
    stage.removeChild(wallArray[index - 2]);
}
```

So with that minor modifications, and adding in the constructor:

```
myWallCollisionList.addItem(wallArray[0]);
myWallCollisionList.addItem(wallArray[1]);
```

so as to not make null references, everything works fine.